# How to set document-template using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, document-template

```
<DocumentTemplate TargetName="/_layouts/CreatePage.aspx" />
```

How could I set this using powershell?

```
$dst = [Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.$dst.Update($true)]::GetDocumentSetTemplate("/_layouts/CreatePage.aspx")

$dst.Update()
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help?

```
#Upload new document template file from computer
$newTemplateFile = Get-ChildItem "C:\LocalPath\Test Document.dotx"
$templateFolderPath = $web.Url + "/" + $list.RootFolder.Url + "/Forms"
$templateFolder = $web.GetFolder($templateFolderPath)
$uploadPath = $templateFolder.Url + "/" + $newTemplateFile.Name
$spNewTemplateFile = $templateFolder.Files.Add($uploadPath, $newTemplateFile.OpenRead(), $true)

#Change list setting to the template file uploaded
$list.DocumentTemplateUrl = $uploadPath
$list.Update()
```

Ref: [updating template.doc in a sharepoint 2010 document library via powershell](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/e177ce72-d535-4a7d-82bb-366023301d3e/updating-templatedoc-in-a-sharepoint-2010-document-library-via-powershell?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)